# Background receiving data while activity isn't running

Tags: android, real-time

I develop client-server app. Android client get real-time text data from server.
While app still active(activity on foreground) data show on screen.
Background service connect to server and sending intents, BroadcastReceiver on activity receive it.

When user leave activity(activity comes into background) BroadcastReceiver detach and service only show notifications about new data.
I have 2 ways next:

1) Service will save all new data to container, user after returning to activity open this container and draw data. In this case my question is: What the container should i use? What's thread-safe container use to communication beetween activity and service?

2) Service don't worry about save data just notify, but user after returning to activity should send request to server and get all data. In this case user maybe wait a long time.

Second way more simple than first, but force user wait isn't good.(async don't solve it)

What are you using in your projects? I think this is common case, but google doesn't help me, probably my search was bad.